# Looking for 1901 birth/baptismal certificate in Poland?

Tags: census-records, birth-records, marriage-records, poland

I am trying to locate my grandfather's birth record, his parents' marriage certificate or anything else that will help me delve back into my family's history in Poland.

Grandfather:  Jan Zaluga, born December 23, 1901, in either Osmolin or Aleksandrow

His Parents:  Feliks Zaluga born or lived in Sanniki and Marianna or Maria Jablonska

My grandfather's passport number as shown on Canadian Immigration Landed Immigrant list is either I67 or 167 and his place of birth on the passport is listed as Aleksandrow. Passport was issued on 9/3/1928

All of the villages named above are in the County of Gostynin.

Can anyone help me out please ?  I have looked on Ancestry.com and other genealogy websites but have turned up empty so far.

Answer (score 3):

To get my father in laws birth certificate necessitated a trip to the record office in Poland. The certificate itself was not expensive, the language was more of a challenge until we found someone who spoke a little English. I have seen reports of people emailing the register office and getting a response, we did not when we tried it. I would suggest that you try an email in Polish if at all possible to the record office. Be aware though that Poland has fairly strict data protection laws and you may be asked to justify the request.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I will look into getting my mother to write an email for me as she writes perfect Polish.  Do you have any idea where I would find the email addresses of the registry office ?  Thank you so much again for your advice!!!

Comment: If the person is deceased and you are a descendant, then that's reason enough for you to obtain the records. However, you might be ask for some kind of proof of your identity - that's why it usually has to be done in person.

Comment: @Jennifer take a look at http://www.archiwa.gov.pl/pl/data-bases/388-vital-records-and-civil-registers-pradziad.html

Comment: I am the granddaughter and have proof of lineage so hopefully they will accept copies of my birth certificate, and my my mother's birth certificate as sufficient reason to allow me to order my grandfather's Polish documents.  Thank you again skolima!

Comment: Hi Colin, I looked at this website but haven't been able to figure out how to use it so I am going to email them and perhaps they will be able to do the search for a fee ... At this point, any and all assistance is so very much appreciated!  Thank you again!!

Comment: The problem I am having is that I do not know which registry office to email ...

Answer (score 3):

Further to this original question FamilySearch are having a webinar on Tuesday 12th May 2015 on using Polish digitised records. Full details [on the FamilySearch Blog](https://familysearch.org/blog/en/digitized-images-polish-state-archives/), or on the Research Wiki page [Online Webinars from the International and Scandinavian Research Teams](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Online_Webinars_from_the_International_and_Scandinavian_Research_Teams). This may help you find out how to get access to the records you require.

The handout for the webinar, [How to Use the Digitized Records of the Polish State Archives](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/images/a/a1/How_to_Use_the_Digitized_Records_of_the_Polish_State_Archives%29.pdf), is available for download, along with other materials for Poland, in the downloads section at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I've added some information about the upcoming webinar to your answer, since the handout for the webinar is available for download.

Answer (score 2):

The Polish government has started moving archives on-line. A good place to start when looking records that are more than 100 years old is the [szukajwarchiwach](http://www.szukajwarchiwach.pl/) site (the name means 'search in archives').

If your ancestors were Roman Catholic and from the Lwów diocese, this [link](http://www.agad.gov.pl/inwentarze/KMLw301.xml) is a veritable treasure trove.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!  I just found out that the 3 villages involved are Sanniki, Osmolin and Aleksandrow which are all in the County of Gostynin.  And the parish church is located in the Village of Sanniki.  Do you know if the Lwow diocese covers the County of Gostynin ... I am having trouble reading the maps and my Polish is very limited ....

Comment: Gostynin and the other towns fall under the diocese of Płock: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Catholic_Diocese_of_P%C5%82ock

Comment: Thank you for this information regarding the diocese of Plock!