# Finding 1894 birth record for ancestor born in Poland?

Tags: birth-records, poland, 1890s

How do I find my great grandfather's birth record?

His name was Victor Godlewski born in Poland on April 6,1894.

I have been using familysearch.org for researching but don't get anything on where in Poland or who his parents were. All I found was his WW2 draft registration card, his citizenship.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Your question may be considered a duplicate of https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/8098/looking-for-1901-birth-baptismal-certificate-in-Poland so I recommend reviewing the answers there.

Comment: In which town was he born? What religion was he when he was born? These questions will help figure out where to look. Where did he live in the US? What was his wife's name? This will help connect him to US records, of which there seem to be many, but conflicting records with that name.

Comment: What other records do you have apart from his WW2 Draft Registration.  You say "his citizenship" -- do you mean you have a certificate of Naturalization? Have you located his Petition for Naturalization and his Declaration yet?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.lostshoebox.com/poland/online-records/

I have used the above link. It is helpful because there is a map where each district shows the numbers to which the matching number is a database that includes material for that area.